# BigBird, or Sparse self-attention: How to implement a sparse matrix?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, tensor, bert-language-model, attention-model

This question is related to the new paper: [Big Bird: Transformers for Longer Sequences](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/c8512d142a2d849725f31a9a7a361ab9-Paper.pdf). Mainly, about the implementation of the Sparse Attention (that is specified in the [Supplemental material, part D](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/c8512d142a2d849725f31a9a7a361ab9-Supplemental.pdf)). Currently, I am trying to implement it in PyTorch.

They suggest a new way to speed up the computation by blocking the original query and key matrices (see, below) [image: attention with block-matrices]

When you do the matrix multiplaciton in the step (b), you end up with something like that:
[image: diagonal attention].

So I was wondering: **how would you go from that representation (image above) to a sparse matrix (using PyTorch, see below)?** In the paper, they just say: "*simply reshape the result*", and I do not know any easy ways to do so (especially, when I have multiple blocks in different positions (see step (c) on the first image).

[image: matrix with dioganal attention]

**RESOLUTION**:
Huggingface has an implementation of BigBird in pytorch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up following the guidelines in the paper. When it comes to the unpacking of the result I use: `torch.sparse_coo_tensor`

EDIT: Sparse tensors are still memory-hungry! The [more efficient solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65571114/add-blocks-of-values-to-a-tensor-at-specific-locations-in-pytorch) is described here

Comment: do you have a sparse attention mechanism implementation?

Comment: you can look at deepspeed implementation

Comment: UPDATE: Huggingface has an implementation of BigBird in pytorch (you can look into their code)

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check, I am also looking for a simple technique for self-supervised learning, please let me know if you have information about it