# Add blocks of values to a tensor at specific locations in PyTorch

Tags: python, performance, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a list of indices:

```
indx = torch.LongTensor([
    [ 0,  2,  0],
    [ 0,  2,  4],
    [ 0,  4,  0],
    [ 0, 10, 14],
    [ 1,  4,  0],
    [ 1,  8,  2],
    [ 1, 12,  0]
])
```

And I have a tensor of `2x2` blocks:

```
blocks = torch.FloatTensor([
    [[1.5818, 2.3108],
     [2.6742, 3.0024]],

    [[2.0472, 1.6651],
     [3.2807, 2.7413]],

    [[1.5587, 2.1905],
     [1.9231, 3.5083]],

    [[1.6007, 2.1426],
     [2.4802, 3.0610]],

    [[1.9087, 2.1021],
     [2.7781, 3.2282]],

    [[1.5127, 2.6322],
     [2.4233, 3.6836]],

    [[1.9645, 2.3831],
     [2.8675, 3.3770]]
])
```

What I want to do is to add each block at an index position to another tensor (i.e. so that it starts at that index). Let's assume that I want to add it to the following tensor:

```
a = torch.ones([2,18,18])
```

Is there any efficient way to do so? So far I came up only with:

```
i = 0
for b, x, y in indx:
   a[b, x:x+2, y:y+2] += blocks[i]
   i += 1
```

It is quite inefficient, I also tried to use `index_add`, but it did not work properly.

Comment: I edited the code, so it is clearer. All in all, I want to add these blocks to matrix 'a' at different positions.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` (values in 2nd and 3rd column of `indx`) always even?

Comment: Yes, they are always even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to index on three different dimensions at the same time. I had a look around in the documentation, [`torch.index_add`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_) will only receive a vector as index. My hopes were on [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) but it doesn't to fit well to this problem. As it turns out you can achieve this <s>pretty easily</s> with a little work, the most difficult parts are the setup and teardown. *Please hang on tight*.

I'll use a simplified example here, but the same can be applied with larger tensors.

```
>>> indx 
tensor([[ 0,  2,  0],
        [ 0,  2,  4],
        [ 0,  4,  0]]))

>>> blocks
tensor([[[1.5818, 2.3108],
         [2.6742, 3.0024]],

        [[2.0472, 1.6651],
         [3.2807, 2.7413]],

        [[1.5587, 2.1905],
         [1.9231, 3.5083]]])

>>> a
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

The main issue here is that you are looking index with slicing. That not possible in a vectorize form. To counter that though you can convert your `a` tensor into `2x2` chunks. This will be particulary handy since we will be able to access sub-tensors such as `a[0, 2:4, 4:6]` with just `a[0, 1, 2]`. Since the `2:4` slice on `dim=1` will be grouped together on `index=1` while the `4:6` slice on `dim=0` will be grouped on `index=2`.

**First** we will convert `a` to tensor made up of `2x2` chunks. **Then** we will update with `blocks`. `Finally`, we will stitch back the resulting tensor into the original shape.

---

### 1. Converting `a` to a *`2x2`-chunks tensor*

You can use a combination of [`torch.chunk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.chunk.html?highlight=chunk#torch.chunk) and [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html?highlight=cat#torch.cat) (not `torch.dog`) twice: on `dim=1` and `dim=2`. The shape of `a` is `(1, h, w)` so we're looking for a result of shape `(1, h//2, w//2, 2, 2)`.

To do so we will unsqueeze two axes on `a`:

```
>>> a_ = a[:, None, :, None, :]
>>> a_.shape
torch.Size([1, 1, 6, 1, 6])
```

Then make *3* chunks on `dim=2`, then concatenate on `dim=1`:

```
>>> a_row_chunks = torch.cat(torch.chunk(a_, 3, dim=2), dim=1)
>>> a_row_chunks.shape
torch.Size([1, 3, 2, 1, 6])
```

And make *3* chunks on `dim=4`, then concatenate on `dim=3`:

```
>>> a_col_chunks  = torch.cat(torch.chunk(a_row_chunks, 3, dim=4), dim=3)
>>> a_col_chunks.shape
torch.Size([1, 3, 2, 3, 2])
```

Finally reshape all.

```
>>> a_chunks = a_col_chunks.reshape(1, 3, 3, 2, 2)
```

Create a new index with adjusted values for our new tensor with. Essentially we divide all values by *2* except for the first column which is the index of `dim=0` in `a` which was unchanged. There's some fiddling around with the types (*in short: it has to be a float in order to divide by 2 but needs to be cast back to a long in order for the indexing to work*):

```
>>> indx_ = indx.clone().float()
>>> indx_[:, 1:] /= 2
>>> indx_ = indx_.long()
tensor([[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 2, 0]])
```

### 2. Updating with `blocks`

We will simply index and accumulate with:

```
>>> a_chunks[indx_[:, 0], indx_[:, 1], indx_[:, 2]] += blocks
```

### 3. Putting it back together

I thought that was it, but actually converting `a_chunk` back to a `6x6` tensor is way trickier than it seems. Apparently `torch.cat` can only receive a *tuple*. I won't go into to much detail: `tuple()` will only consider the first axis, as a workaround you can use [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=permute#torch.Tensor.permute) to switch the axes. This combined with two `torch.cat` will do:

```
>>> a_row_cat = torch.cat(tuple(a_chunks.permute(1, 0, 2, 3, 4)), dim=2)
>>> a_row_cat.shape
torch.Size([1, 3, 6, 2])

>>> A = torch.cat(tuple(a_row_cat.permute(1, 0, 2, 3)), dim=2)
>>> A.shape
torch.Size([1, 6, 6])

>>> A
tensor([[[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [1.5818, 2.3108, 0.0000, 0.0000, 2.0472, 1.6651],
         [2.6742, 3.0024, 0.0000, 0.0000, 3.2807, 2.7413],
         [1.5587, 2.1905, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [1.9231, 3.5083, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]])
```

*Et voilà.*

---

If you didn't quite get how the chunks worked. Run this:

```
for x in range(0, 6, 2):
    for y in range(0, 6, 2):
        a *= 0
        a[:, x:x+2, y:y+2] = 1
        print(a)
```

And see for yourself: each `2x2` block of `1`s corresponds to a chunk in `a_chunks`.

So you can do the same with:

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        a_chunks *= 0
        a_chunks[:, x, y] = 1
        print(a_chunks)
```